# Cocos2D-JS scene transition

Tags: javascript, transition, scene, cocos2d-js

I used Cocos Studio to create a 2 scenes, 1 with 1 button, and 1 with 2 buttons.

I'd like to be able to transition from scene by the press of the button - I opened my project in Cocos Code IDE, how can I target the button that I created in the studio?

Answer (score 0):

```
cc.director.runScene(new SceneName())
```

and in the second Scene you have

```
var LayerName = cc.Layer({})
var SceneName = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter: function() {
        this._super();
        var layer = new LayerName();
        this.addChild(layer);
    }
});
```